# Error importing animated file from Blender to Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, import, blender

I'm having issues importing this files in Unity https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1bspUVIs8QH9KYdgHFIelHQTSINse78FZ
When open them in Unity, I see a cube instead of the petals of the flower (both if I import it as a .blend or .fbx)
Do you now why does it happens?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that it's a procedural model and not a "normal" Mesh. If I export as .fbx from blender and then import again, there's also just a cube. You'll have to somehow convert the procedural mesh into a static one.